# Relational Model vs. Database Products

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

The formal Relational Model (logical level) for databases is not exactly the same thing as you get with MySQL, Oracle or other major products / implementations of ‘relational’ database management systems and SQL (physical level). Other than terminology (relation vs. table, attribute vs. column, tuple vs. row), what are some of the major differences? Why are there such differences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL allows some things that work against the concept of the relational model:

- Duplicate rows
- NULLs
- Left-to-right column ordering
- Unnamed columns and duplicate column names
- etc.

Chris Date is pretty clear that he thinks SQL doesn't implement the relational model properly. He uses an alternative query language in his books that he calls Tutorial D.

You might like to read some of Date's books to read what he has to say about it.

- [Database in Depth](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100124.do)
- [SQL and Relational Theory](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022879.do)

[Dataphor](http://www.dataphor.org/) is a relational database product that does not use SQL, and reportedly implements the relational model better than SQL.

Comment: i am not able to figure out What can be the differences ? and why are they ?

Comment: Rel (http://dbappbuilder.sourceforge.net/Rel.php) is an implementation of Tutorial D.

Comment: @Sonali, SQL was designed by committee to solve business needs. It was not designed to be a faithful implementation of relational theory.